# Updated PayPal but why "Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\REST\ApiContext' not found"?

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am moving my PHP application from localhost to online server and I receive an error: Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\REST\ApiContext' not found.
I have tired to update the PayPal SDK as suggested in other posts. Still getting this error with the ApiContext. My code for the start file is below. I have implemented the fix described in other posts to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

use PayPal\REST\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

session_start();
include('connect.php');

//determine if user signed in

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
$userPAYPAL = $_SESSION['uid'];
} else {
header("Location:../../register.php");
}


require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

//create new PayPal API context (ERROR OCCURS HERE)
$api = new ApiContext(
new OAuthTokenCredential(

'AZp2HH9aWL2QxjVZRO51N33ZLqweiO5x_GPIyUMWgqLYhe0yxfQSPhJaUkCyqx8OHT',

'EGpHg8K23idpNF895v6Zm4rybajrvAoED6T0As0NUk4q2fhJ7oDv82z1PKTECiHfkl'
)
);

$api->setConfig([
'mode' => 'sandbox',
'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
'log.LogEnabled' => false,
'log.FileName' => '',
'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
'validation.level' => 'log'

]);
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Switched to answer mode, since I realized that was the issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you are seeing the discrepancy due to case sensitivity. You have at the top of your code:

```
use PayPal\REST\ApiContext;
```

When it is defined in their code with a `Rest` like:

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
```

---

On a side note, the way I like to use the `paypal rest sdk`, is when I'm calling any of their objects or methods, I just use the full namespace... like `$apiContext = new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext( .. );` and `$addr = new PayPal\Api\Address();` etc. That way I don't clash my own code with the `use`.