# Why error Class 'PayPal\REST\ApiContext' not found when PayPal SDK uploaded to server?

Tags: php, paypal

My PHP application was working on my localhost and now I upload to server to receive the error Class 'PayPal\REST\ApiContext' not found. I had a similar problem where the the require '/../vendor/autoload.php'; wasn't being accessed. I have made sure that that line is accessable. I didn't see a clear answer and thought to post seeing if any ideas. I compressed the SDK and unpacked in the file manager on the server. Any help would be appreciated. I have looked at the documentation and followed outlines to a T. When the error is displayed the address bar says http://www.mattmacy.com/greenia/Composer_Paypal_SDK/member/payment.php?link=8&ANON=8 . This leads me to believe there is some conflict in the payment file. It said on a post to remove the first '/' from /../vendor/autoload.php but this only raised another error.

```
use PayPal\REST\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

session_start();
include('connect.php');

if (!empty($_GET['ANON'])){
    $ANONYMOUS = $_GET['ANON'];
} 

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
$userPAYPAL = $_SESSION['uid'];
//ANONYMOUS is memembers_id
} elseif (!empty($_GET['ANON'])){
//$memberPAYPAL = $ANONYMOUS;
$userPAYPAL = $ANONYMOUS;
//echo "ANONYMOUS set";
}elseif (!empty($_GET['link'])){
$MP3_id  = $_GET['link']; 

header("Location: ../src/wouldYouLiketoRegister.php?link=".$MP3_id);

} 


require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

//create new PayPal API context
$api = new ApiContext(
new OAuthTokenCredential(

'AZp2HH9aWL2QxjVZRO51N33ZLqweiO5x_GPIyUMWgqLYhe0yxfQSPhJaUkCyqx',
'EGpHg8K23idpNF895v6Zm4rybajrvAoED6T0As0NUk4q2fhJ7oDv82z1PK'
 )
);
```

Comment: How did you install the the paypal sdk?

Comment: I installed with composer. I figured this out REST needed to be changed to Rest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated PayPal but why "Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\REST\ApiContext' not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671347/updated-paypal-but-why-fatal-error-class-paypal-rest-apicontext-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

This needed to be changed from use PayPal\REST\ApiContext; to Rest